# Merge databases with sql only: firefox places and visits

Tags: sqlite, merge

I have two tables in each of two dbs:

`places: id, url (unique),`

`visits: id, place_id, timestamp, type.`

I need to merge those databases:

1. There are one main database and one "to-merge". The unique data should be added to the main database (of course with new ids).
2. Source dbs may contain same `places` and `visits` rows but some of them can be with different ids.
3. Two `visits` rows are equal when their `timestamp`, `type` columns and `places.url` are equal.
4. Two `places` rows are equal when their `url` columns are equal.
5. `place_id` should be corrected for merged `visits`.

I can attach databases with `ATTACH ... AS ...`.

I've already done this with C# code but that solution seems to be a kind of overcomplicated (I have it on github). I'm wondering if it's possible to merge them with sql only? How would you do that?